# Can't understand why Master Theorem fits or not a given recurrence relation

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

I'm posting here $2$ little parts of "[Introduction to Algorithms](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms)" by *Thomas H. Cormen* (2009):

- First example:

[image: First example]

- Second example:

[image]

As you can see, in the first picture we can apply the Master Theorem (*MT*) and we are in the third *MT* case.
Whereas in the second picture we can't apply the Master Theorem because The ratio $f(n) / n^{\log_b a}$ that is equal to $n \lg n$ is asymptotically less than $n^\epsilon$ for any positive constant $\epsilon$.

I can't understand why MT fits the first example, because if we try to solve the ratio (like we did in the second example) $f(n) / n^{\log_b a}$ we get $(n^{0.207}) \lg n$ that it doesn't seem to be greater than $n^\epsilon$.

### ------

I think that I forgot a little detail: $ε$ *should be an arbitrarily small quantity*.

Here is the Master Theorem definition in the textbook:

[image: Master Theorem definition]

The textbook just indicates that $ε>0$, so I have considered *all* positive numbers greater than $0$.

But

1. if we assume that $ε$ is a *small quantity near the zero*, like $ε=0.1$ or $ε=0.2$,
2. and we take a *sufficiently large* $n$, like $n=2^{60}$,

   then $(n^{0.207}) \lg n$ is greater than $n^ε$.

This is an assumption I've made, help me understand if it's correct.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Please look at [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to easily make your posts more attractive to other readers. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

$(n^{0.207})\lg n$ must be asymptotically greater than $n^{\epsilon}$ for some $\epsilon \gt 0$ . And that is true, for example $\epsilon = 0.207$ will do the job.

Answer (score -1):

I think that I forgot a little detail:
*$\epsilon$ should be an arbitrarily small quantity*.

Here is the Master Theorem definition in "[Introduction to Algorithms](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms)" by *Thomas H. Cormen*(2009):

[image: Master theorem]

The textbook just indicates that $\epsilon\gt 0$, so I have considered *all* positive numbers greater than $0$.

But if we assume that $\epsilon$ is a *small quantity near the zero*, like $\epsilon = 0.1$ or $\epsilon = 0.2$, then $(n^{0.207}) \lg n$ is greater than $n^\epsilon$.

For example, with $n=1024$ and $\epsilon \le 0.5$ we have that $(n^{0.207}) \lg n$ is greater than $n^\epsilon$.

Comment: I suggest that you place this additional information at the end of your original post since this is not an answer to your question.

Comment: Additional information added. Thank you.